# How do I make my website load prettier?

Tags: image, graphics, load, rendering

My website seems to take on this "squeegee" type load effect, where all of the graphics load from the top down with an ugly top to bottom wiping effect. Is there a way to make the actual way in which your website renders graphics prettier?

Comment: Do you load a lot of large graphics that are resized with HTML?  I once saw this page with a 2MB image that was resized to like `100x75` or something on the client, and it would slowly draw from top to bottom.

Comment: Some are resized, others are not. Would you suggest some site-wide "loading .gif"? I think I'd rather have something like that than this gross wiping effect.

Comment: @Matt, what Mike means is that you should give the explicit sizes for all images so that the browser engine knows their final position even before they are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be more interested in why your page is taking so long to load and/or render.  If it takes several seconds to draw, even on a fast connection, you might want to look into why that is.  Tools such as Fiddler, Firebug, IE Developer Tools, etc can help you look at what resources your page is downloading and how big each research is.

If you have massive resources on the page (such as BMP or PNG files that are several hundred K), see if you can convert them to other formats or resize them on the server to the size they render at.

If your HTML is massively complex, such as huge nested tables, you might want to look into simplifying that with more modern HTML and CSS styling.

If you do have huge, high-res bitmaps that need to be loaded, you might want to preload them with script and then render them dynamically when they finish loading.